# What is the complexity of find and checking prime numbers?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to figure out the complexities of these two functions that I've written but could not understand.def

First, I thought it is supposed be `O(N)`. But it is not clear how many times the loop run because I have no idea how many prime numbers could be found.

```
def self.find_primes(n)
    primes = []
    total = 0
    i = 2

    while total < n do
      if is_prime i
        primes.push i
        total += 1
      end

      i += 1
    end

    primes
end
```

In the second function, it is supposed to be `O(N/2)`.

```
def self.is_prime n
    (2..n/2).none?{|i| n % i == 0}
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop is O(N). The inner loop is O(N/2), which is just O(N). Therefore, the function as a whole is O(N^2). Knowing the number of primes that could be found doesn't affect time complexity, since time complexity is a function of N, i.e., it increases or decreases with N.

Comment: The first function calls the second in a loop... This is O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks, Bailey. You're correct. I thought they were two separate functions. Didn't notice that the second function was called in the first.